# Parseando JSON con jq

Tags: json, csv, parsear

Al consultar un `API` obtengo el siguiente `JSON`:

```
{
  "Count": 1,
  "Data": [
    {
      "BlockedCount": 0,
      "BouncedCount": 0,
      "ClickedCount": 0,
      "DeferredCount": 0,
      "DeliveredCount": 0,
      "HardBouncedCount": 0,
      "LastActivityAt": "",
      "OpenedCount": 0,
      "PreQueuedCount": 0,
      "ProcessedCount": 0,
      "QueuedCount": 0,
      "SenderID": 69059,
      "SoftBouncedCount": 0,
      "SpamComplaintCount": 0,
      "UnsubscribedCount": 0,
      "WorkFlowExitedCount": 0
    }
  ],
  "Total": 1
}
```

Y necesito generar un fichero .`CSV` con la siguiente info:

```
"Count","BlockedCount","BouncedCount","ClickedCount","DeferredCount","DeliveredCount","HardBouncedCount","LastActivityAt","OpenedCount","PreQueuedCount","ProcessedCount","QueuedCount","SenderID","SoftBouncedCount","SpamComplaintCount","UnsubscribedCount","WorkFlowExitedCount","Total"

"1","0","0","0","0","0","0"," ","0","0","0","0","69059","0","0","0","0","1"
```

Donde la primera linea son los rótulos de los datos y la segunda linea los valores para cada uno de ellos.

Estoy intentando generar esto utilizando jq pero todavía no lo estoy obteniendo, mi mayor dificultad la tengo a la hora de tratar con el elemento .`Data` que es un array de un elemento, pero que dentro tiene un formato `JSON`:

```
"Data": [
    {
      "BlockedCount": 0,
      "BouncedCount": 0,
      "ClickedCount": 0,
      "DeferredCount": 0,
      "DeliveredCount": 0,
      "HardBouncedCount": 0,
      "LastActivityAt": "",
      "OpenedCount": 0,
      "PreQueuedCount": 0,
      "ProcessedCount": 0,
      "QueuedCount": 0,
      "SenderID": 69059,
      "SoftBouncedCount": 0,
      "SpamComplaintCount": 0,
      "UnsubscribedCount": 0,
      "WorkFlowExitedCount": 0
    }
  ],
```

Si lo filtro de esta forma js `.Data[0]` obtengo la salida en JSON:

```
{
  "BlockedCount": 0,
  "BouncedCount": 0,
  "ClickedCount": 0,
  "DeferredCount": 0,
  "DeliveredCount": 0,
  "HardBouncedCount": 0,
  "LastActivityAt": "",
  "OpenedCount": 0,
  "PreQueuedCount": 0,
  "ProcessedCount": 0,
  "QueuedCount": 0,
  "SenderID": 69059,
  "SoftBouncedCount": 0,
  "SpamComplaintCount": 0,
  "UnsubscribedCount": 0,
  "WorkFlowExitedCount": 0
}
```

Pero aún no sé cómo puedo armar todo junto, agradecería alguna ayuda.

Comment: Hola Luis Calvo, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado.  Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Con "jq" te refieres a jQuery o a https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jq?

Comment: ¿Puedes poner en las etiquetas o completar la pregunta con el lenguaje que estás usando?

Comment: @Kiko_L si, con jq me refiero a [./jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)